# Delphi - How to get last error message when working with unit 'Web.Win.ADsTypes'

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10-seattle, adsi

In my program, I am using the ADSI objects to make LDAP queries.
I am using the ADsGetObject function which is located at Web.Win.ADsTypes.

If the function fails or i get a bad result, i want to raise an exception.
I wrote some similar code using the Windows unit where i could use the GetLastError function like this

```
raise Exception.Create('Error ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError()));
```

and it gave me the last error that occurred.

I seek to know if there is a similar function which I can use in order to see the last error that occurred while using 'Web.Win.ADsTypes'.

Comment: I found on msdn that I can use the 'ADsGetLastError ' function. but I don`t know in what unit it is located since it always gives me the undeclared identifier error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the documentation of [ADsGetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772184(v=vs.85).aspx) correctly, you have to pass the value returned by ADsGetObject to the `SysErrorMessage()`.
I think your code should look something like this:

```
rc := ADsGetObject(...);
if S_OK <> rc then raise Exception.Create('Error ' + SysErrorMessage(rc));
```

Comment: Thanks, for somewhat i didn't think it would show me the matching error description.